# plsql if control different calculation

Tags: if-statement, plsql

I am using PLSQL to realize some of the function below.

I have the table which have piece level data with each piece weight. Basically I want to realize the following function:

1. if piece weight is over 1 LB. groupby ceil(weight) (next LB)
2. if piece weight is less 1 LB  groupby cell(weight*16) ( Next OZ)

I am just curious how can I realize that in plsql. I feel I need to have the if statement. But I am not sure how to do that.

(Weight is already an variable in that table, do I need to declare here?)

```
        begin
            if weight <1 then
              select ceil(weight*16),sum(weight)
            from ops_owner.track_mail_item
            where manifestdate = '24-aug-2016'
            group by ceil(weight*16)

            else select ceil(weight),sum(weight)
            from ops_owner.track_mail_item
            where manifestdate = '24-aug-2016'
            end if,
            end;
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would adjust the weight value in an inline view, I think.

```
select
  ceil(adjusted_weight),
  sum(adjusted_weight)
from
  (
  select
    case
      when weight < 1 then weight * 16
      else weight
    end adjusted_weight
  from
    ops_owner.track_mail_item
  where
    manifestdate = '24-aug-2016'
    )
group by
  ceil(adjusted_weight);
```